# Compute the most common array elements

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a bunch of documents containing an array of tags:

```
{ tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }
```

What I'd like to do is to compute the top 10 most common tags used among all documents. After some trial-and-error I've come up with the following solution:

```
r.db("database").table("table").concatMap(function(doc) {
  return doc("tags")
}).coerceTo("array").group(function(entry) {
  return entry
}).count().ungroup().orderBy(r.desc("reduction").limit(10).map(function(doc) {
  return doc("group")
})
```

However, I "feel" (with my limited knowledge of query optimization) that this a rather cumbersome way to do it. Can anyone suggest a more efficient approach with proper use of indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query looks fine to me except for the `coerceTo('array')`, which I don't think is necessary and which will probably affect performance.  You can also shorten it quite a bit:

```
r.table('table').group('tags', {multi: true}).count().ungroup().orderBy('reduction').slice(-10)('group')
```

Comment: Thanks! Good use of the multi-index. The `.orderBy(r.desc("reduction"))` is missing from your answer. Is there actually any difference between `slice(-10)` and `limit(10)` performance-wise?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I forgot the `orderBy`.  I left off the `r.desc`; `slice(-10)` takes the last 10 elements instead of the first 10.  Since we're operating on an array here it should be just as efficient.